# Apply background color to parent table th only

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table structure, where I can't access jsp file to add class files. I have to manage it through CSS. In this case, I need to apply background color for first table all th's. Not to nested table th's. How can we do this with CSS? Example : http://jsfiddle.net/qdDnJ/

Answer (score 2):

As per i understand may you can write like this:

```
tr th{
    background:red;
}
tr table th{
    background:none;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/qdDnJ/2/

Comment: is it possible without using background:none ?

Comment: i am override the color of above color. If you want different color or an image you can apply on it.

Answer (score 1):

Distinguish first table's `th` from the second table's `th`.

**Edited after comment:**

See here, http://jsfiddle.net/qdDnJ/25/

I have assumed that `div` is parent container of first table.

You can replace it with table's parent.

e.g. If `body` is parent, css should be,

```
    body > table > tbody > tr > th {
      background-color:red;
    }
```

Comment: i need without using any css class

Comment: Then, whats the problem in @Sandeep's answer ?

If you still dont want to use that, I've edited my answer. Do look at it.

Comment: @PavanKumar: Jashwant's CSS does not contain classes. It relies on child combinator (`>`) which is most appropriate solution to target exact nesting level.

Comment: Excellent Solutions. working well. Can you please explain how it is working with your single css line?

Comment: @PavanKumar As Marat explained I used `>` . It selects the direct children (not descendants).

See this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006b.html. And please mark answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
table th:first-child {
    background: red;
}
table table th:first-child {
    background: none;
}​
```

I would just give the outer table a class and use this:

```
table.class-name th:first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know is to use the child selector

```
#yourtableId > tbody > tr > th { background: red; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/qdDnJ/26/)

Comment: can you apply to my example and send it back? bcoz i cant get it with your code.

Comment: OP said "I have to manage it through css". So, may be he have no access for html.

Comment: @sandeep, I dont know what may be and what may not be

Answer (score 0):

Every body tried many things to achieve the target as per the question.

but as per the HTML we can just write the following css and avoid child th to get background-color..

in this solution we do not need any id and class or any thing accept the `.gap class`. Even if this class is not there we can apply the css.

check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qdDnJ/22/)

**HERE is the CSS with `.gap` class**

```
table th {background-color:red;}
table td.gap tr th {background:none;}
```

**HERE is the CSS without `.gap` class**

```
table th {background-color:red;}
table td tr th {background:none;}
```